# Getting unnecessary values in ngx-formly form.value

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

Summary:

Using ngx-formly, I want to create a form whose value is this:

```
[
      {
        investment_name: [
           "Investment 1",
           "Investment 2",
           "Investment 3"
        ]
      },
      {
       investor_name: [
           "John",
           "Tom",
           "Tim"
          ]
        }
  ]
```

---

**What I tried:**

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formly-starter-example-8rptay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I am using following `field` value but I am getting incorrect `form.value` with extra field (SEE LINE A AND B). Also it would be awesme if I could avoid "main" key but its not necessary.

```
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'main',
      type: 'repeat',
      fieldArray: {
        fieldGroupClassName: 'row',
        fieldGroup: [
          {
            key: 'text',
            type: 'input-repeat',
          },
          {
            key: 'name',
            type: 'input-repeat',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
```

**form.value I am getting is this (see LINE A AND B):**

```
   {
      "main": [
        {
          "text": [
            "Investment 1",
            "Investment 2",
            "Investment 3"
          ],
          "name": [] // LINE A: I DONT WANT THIS
        },
        {
          "text": [], //LINE B: I DONT WANT THIS
          "name": [
            "John",
            "Tom",
            "Tim"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `fields` config with the following:

```
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      type: 'repeat',
      key: 'main',
      fieldArray: {
        fieldGroupClassName: 'row',
        fieldGroup: [
          {
            fieldArray:{
            type: 'input-repeat',
            key: 'text',
            }
          },
          {
            fieldArray:{
            type: 'input-repeat',
            key: 'name',
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
```

I have added a `fieldArray` for both the `text` and `name` fields.

This is necessary because in your model, you have an array of values instead of a single value. This is also the reason why two additional empty fields, name and text, were generated.

[image]

Comment: I can't change my modal. Only thing I can change is fields.

Comment: thanks for letting me know! I have edit my answer. Please check if this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. but can you add explaination on why my code doesnt work and your works? you have removed "main" from fields. shouldn't it be present in fields if its present in modal?

Comment: My last solution was only a work around. I have now edited my response to provide a more proper solution.

Comment: Its a great solution. Can you pls explain why adding fieldArray inside fieldGroup fixes the problem? Where can I read more about fieldArray and fieldGroup. I thought these two are only used for layout purposes

Comment: Check this: 

https://formly.dev/docs/examples/advanced/repeating-section